# Error in Android Studio - "Please provide the path to the Android SDK"

Tags: java, android-studio, sdk

[image: screenshot]

I recently formatted my computer, and as a result some of the files got deleted, then I downloaded the newest version of Android Studio. After downloading, I opened Android Studio and the above showed up to me. I tried downloading a new sdk from the link there, but it still didn't work.

My path is `C:\Users\(Former name of my computer)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
I tried changing it to the new name but I couldn't find a \Sdk in my new Android Path.

Where do I download an SDK and where do I place it, if it's the problem? Or, is the problem something else?

Comment: restarting and formatting are completely different things

Answer (score 0):

In this link, you can get [SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=CjwKCAjwu5CDBhB9EiwA0w6sLXrgYhbdAIW6LwL4FAP-T0peXD0lftWlxU5KUAGuhOFOgy0wXrTkQRoCWIMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Check your env's , ANDROID_HOME, and others, check if paths are correct.